# Does anyone have the 1996 correspondence game between De Groot-Simmelink?

Tags: correspondence-chess, master-games

As far as I know, here are the first 12.5 moves are as below. Does anyone have the rest of the game?

```
[FEN ""]

1. d4 Nf6 2. c4 Nc6 3. Nc3 e5 4. d5 Ne7 5. h4 Neg8 6. a3 a6 7. Nf3 Ng4 8.
Ng5 f5 9. Qc2 Bc5 10. e3 Ne7 11. Be2 Nf6 12. b4 Ba7 13. Bb2
```

Comment: Out of curiosity, what is your source for those first moves of the game?

Comment: It is quoted in Richard Palliser's Play 1.d4 pp 278 (Batsford 2003.)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This question seems to have been answered by TD in [ChessPub Forum](http://www.chesspub.com/cgi-bin/chess/YaBB.pl?num=1435326430/2). I post the answer below:

```
[fen ""]
[Date "1996"]
[Round "?"]
[White "De Groot, Adrianus Dingeman"]
[Black "Simmelink, Joop Theo"]
[Source "ChessBase"]

1. d4 Nf6 2. c4 Nc6 3. Nc3 e5 4. d5 Ne7 5. h4 Neg8 6. a3 a6 7. Nf3 Ng4 8. Ng5 f5 9. Qc2 Bc5 10. e3 Ne7 11. Be2 Nf6 12. b4 Ba7 13. Bb2 h6 14. Nf3 d6 15. c5 e4 16. cxd6 Qxd6 17. Nd2 O-O 18. Rd1 b5 19. Bxb5 axb5 20. Nxb5 Qd7 21. Nxc7 Rb8 22. d6 Nc6 23. Nc4 f4 24. Bxf6 fxe3 25. fxe3 Qg4 26. Nd5 Be6 27. Ne7+ Nxe7 28. dxe7 Qg3+ 29. Qf2 Qxf2+ 30. Kxf2 Rxf6+ 31. Ke1 Kf7 32. Ne5+ Ke8 33. Nc6 Bd7 34. Nxb8 Bxb8 35. Rd4 Ra6 36. Rf1 Bg3+ 37. Kd2 Bc6 38. Rc1 Bb7 39. Rc5 Kxe7 40. Ra5 Rxa5 41. bxa5 Bc7 42. a6 Bxa6 43. Rxe4+ Kf6 44. Rd4 1/2-1/2
```

Comment: I had to ask there ;)

Answer (score 2):

Usually when games cannot be found on free databases, Chessbase is the only way forward. I found this game on Megabase 2014.